# How to get an object inside an array that is inside an object in ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

How would I 'get' the value of a property that is declared inside another property that is inside an array that is inside an object...

Here is an example:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  var express = require('express');
  var thingsRouter = express.Router();
  thingsRouter.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send(
 {

  thing: [
  {
    id: 1,
    year: 2008,
    property: {
      id:1,
      location:"somewhere",
      assessments: [
        {
          assessment:{
            otherId: 1,
            value: 10,
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }]
});
});
  app.use('/api/things', thingsRouter);
};
```

I want to get `value`. How would I get that value in the controller?

If you need more info, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have `THING` stored on the global `App` variable, then you could access `value` in your controller by:

```
var value = App.THING.property.assessments[0].assessment.value;
```

I am wondering why you are storing this object as a global. Also, the way you are setting a glocal variable isn't consistent with the way things should be set up in `ember-cli` - instead you should use `imports`, `exports` and `services, but you'll have to provide more detail about what you are generally trying to do in order to get suggestions for a better architecture.